# how to fix waiting for key chord in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

I have a lot of key binding such the following:

```
{
  "key": "; c",
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "when": "editorLangId == vhdl && neovim.mode == insert && editorTextFocus",
  "args": {
    "name": "constant"
   }
}
```

but now i cannot type ; because vscode is waiting for next key chord.
I read here that the added 5s timeout but that is a lot of time to wait. Is there any work around for this?

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/15550

Comment: why don't you define these as snippets and let the prefix manager do its job

Comment: @rioV8 because I am not used to pressing Enter to apply the snippet.